# Spring Integration: Routing messages by content

Tags: spring-integration

Using Spring Integration:

When a message is received it should go to one of 4 different channels based on an attribute in the message. If a specific field in the message begins with A-F it should go to channel 1, G-M to channel 2, etc.

What is the most efficient way to do this?
If it can be visually represented in the STS designer, it is a big plus.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the answes to the same question on the [Spring Forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?140850-Sending-message-to-multiple-channels), the most efficient would be a POJO router

```
<router ... ref="myRouter" .../>
```

where the POJO would return a reference to a `MessageChannel` or a channel name.

But the integration graph won't connect the router to the channels.

You can use a `<recipient-list-router/>` with selector expressions; it will show up nicely in STS, but will be less efficient because the expressions would all be evaluated.